# How do I register an applink in AppDelegte .net Maui

Tags: ios, xamarin, appdelegate, maui, applinks

I want to add applinking in my Maui app. I follow this guide for Xamarin:
https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/

Now I registered my applink for android in MainActivity.cs

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
              DataScheme = "https",
              DataHost = "xxx.com",
              DataPathPrefix = "/Share",
              AutoVerify =true,
              Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
```

In this question James Montemagno (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/app-development/net-maui-applinks/m-p/3090344) mentioned that I have to register the Link in AppDelegate for iOS in a Maui app. The problem: I don't know how to do this.

Could anyone explain me?

Comment: Do you mean the part where you need to add the Associated Links in your Entitlement? I am not sure how info.plist has anything regarding deep linking

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes I mean his part. But in Maui there is no Entitlement. Then I found the post from James where he said you have to do this in AppDelegate.

Comment: Do you have a solution for your issue now?

Comment: Could this help? [Entitlements and capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/entitlements?view=net-maui-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits: LiqunShen-MSFT

Use this Link to create a Entitlements.plist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/entitlements?view=net-maui-7.0

And use this guide to register your domain in it: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Instead of just linking to solutions, you should write a proper answer and explain how to solve the problem at hand, then reference the source of that information.