# Shell navigation with dynamic content

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

To contrive an example, let's say I have an application that catalogs a library of books by author. What I am attempting is a Shell flyout that lists all of the authors and selecting an author from that list will display a page that lists all of the books by that author.

Naively, I would assume that I could have an Author page that could take a route parameter of an author id (`//author/{authorId}` or `//author?authorId={authorId}`). I'm unclear how I would set up flyout items to work with that. The list of authors is loaded dynamically from a web service, can I register custom routes for each item that will resolve to what I'm trying to hit?

How can I set this up or am I really barking up the wrong tree? I get that I could use the `BindingContext` from the `ShellContent` itself, but is that going to be available if I were to do something like use that uri to navigate into the app from another one?

Comment: Did you mean changing FlyoutItem dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Does it help [Dynamically create list of FlyoutItem in Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65911023/dynamically-create-list-of-flyoutitem-in-shell)

Comment: I appreciate it, but no. I can add items at runtime, my concern is about linking into the application from another application using the shell routing. The content is relying heavily on the data context of the item. Is that even available if I'm navigating directly to a route without doing going through the menu?

Comment: Do you mean [open another app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android#open-another-app) using Launcher?

Comment: Almost. I want to deep link into _this_ app from another and still retain that binding context somehow.

Comment: You may refer to some relevant issue : [Deep linking in .NET MAUI app on Android only partially works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282827/deep-linking-in-net-maui-app-on-android-only-partially-works), [How do I register an applink in AppDelegte .net Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877924/how-do-i-register-an-applink-in-appdelegte-net-maui),[App-Linking in Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the flyout item at runtime by adding it in code behind.

Suppose this is a button event handler,

```
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        AppShell.Current.Items.Clear();

        //add new flyout item
        ShellContent content = new ShellContent();
        content.Title = "test";
        content.Content = new MyPage();

        AppShell.Current.Items.Add(content);
    }
```